# Sed command to put /* at start of line and */ at 70 and 71 position of line

Tags: bash, shell, sed, linux-kernel

I am new to bash and writing one automation using bash. I have situation where I need to put /* at the start of line and */ at end of line (position 70, 71) for all lines between 7 and 21.

Before change it should look like

```
  APF ADD                                                              
  DSNAME(FELE00.SFEKAUTH)                                            
  VOLUME(C2PRD1)
```

After Change should look like

```
/*APF ADD                              */                                
/*DSNAME(FELE00.SFEKAUTH)            */                              
/*VOLUME(C2PRD1)                       */
```

And then I would like to do other way round replace /* and */ with spaces

Comment: Don't post images, post the code in the question.

Comment: start with posting and formatting the minimal input and expected output. Also, the last requirement is unclear: if it should replace `/*` with space - why don't enclose the needed lines with space at once?

Comment: Thanks RomanPerekhrest for your input..This is the automation for Mainframe system which we are trying to do from Linux m/c. I have some limitation in modifying the Mainframe system directly. So, The only way is to change it through bash from Linux...In Mainframe /* */ is commenting the code

Comment: @NeerajKumar, can you elaborate the last requirement *And then I would like to do other way round replace /* and */ with spaces* regarding to your desired output?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest...based on parameter to the bash script...User should be able to comment the line from APF ADD to /*APF ADD*/ and vice versa (from /*APF ADD */ to APF ADD)

Comment: Did you tried to google? Say, "sed replace comments". There pretty number of the questions on SO on this topic.

Comment: I did search..I am unable to find something matching with my requirement. I tried several ways..After that I thought of asking question because i need to proceed fast...May be I am not putting right strings in google to search.

Comment: The desired output does not match the description, the `*/` are neither at column 70 nor at the same column for the threes shown lines. Would it be OK to put them simply at the end of the lines?

Comment: Please show your own attempts. That would elegently avoid the impression that you are looking for a free coding service. Things like that might become clearer if you read the [tour].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following command will do the trick.

use file named raw

first sed will put /* at the start of the line remove the double space there

then awk fill up the lines with space to 71 caracter long ( required for second sed to work )

second sed change 70. char to * and 71. char to /

operator >> redirect output to file named processed

```
cat raw | sed 's/^  /\/\*/g' | awk -F "$" '{printf "%-71s\n", $1}' | sed 's/./\//70;s/./\*/71' >> processed
```

Comment: Thanks a lot...I modified your solution a little to use.

Comment: I used something like this  sed -i '21,33{s/./\*/70;s/./\\/71}' "processed"

sed -i '21,33{s/^../\/'"\*"'/}' "processed"  and cat processed | sed '21,33{s/^../'"  "'/}' | awk -F "$" '{printf "%-71s\n", $1}' | sed '21,33{s/./\'" "'/70;s/./\'" "'/71}' > processed1